# How to Modify an MDX calculated measure in a way it's not filtered by a specified dimension member

Tags: powerbi, ssas, mdx

I have an MDX calculated measure named [Measures].[Total Sales]
I'm using this measure in a power BI report.
I have different filters :

- Year
- Region
- Department

I want this measure to ignore the filter Region.
How can I achieve this ?

I tried to use the keyword Existing to

With member [Measures].[Sales Total] AS
Sum(Existing [Region].[Region name].members, [Measures].[Sales])

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchies in cubes have [(All)] members - you can simply use the [(All)] member in region along with the measure - an example using the AdvWks cube:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[reseller Sales Total] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [Geography].[Country].[(All)]
     ,[Measures].[reseller Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[reseller Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[reseller Sales Total]
  } ON 0
 ,[Geography].[Country].[Country] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

As you can see the new measure is ignoring the row filters on country:

[image]